# How does one enable the http CONNECT request on Apache?

Tags: apache, http, proxy

I tried the following on my Apache web server:

```
CONNECT www.example.com:443 HTTP/1.1
host: www.example.com:443
content-length: 0
```

example.com is NOT my web site on that server, it's the target of the proxy tunnel. I got 400 Bad Request in response. So apparently the CONNECT request is disabled. If so how do I enable it?

Edit: I did an OPTIONS request and got the answer

```
Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS
```

So this confirms that CONNECT is disabled.

Edit2: OK so I didn't make myself clear enough, see Mukesh' answer below. My Apache web server is meant to work as a forward proxy server but only for tunneling TLS traffic. The target site example.com sits on ANOTHER server. It's my Apache server that needs to handle CONNECT requests.

Comment: https://geek-university.com/apache/configure-apache-as-a-forward-proxy/

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for the link, but that was complicated and I would like an explanation of how it works. Can't I simply enable the CONNECT method somehow? Do I have to load and enable a special module for handling such requests?

Comment: Yes it is complicated. No, not "simply". Yes. (I have no idea why you would want to use Apache HTTPD as a forward proxy in the first place, there are proxy servers designed to be forward proxies as their core feature).

Comment: @Quentin It's not my computer. If it had been I would have thrown out Apache and installed my very own tailormade tunnel program. But as it is I dare not even beg the webmaster to effect the changes in that link. Do you know of a ready to use tunnel simulating script? I'm thinking about tunneling with http on a persistent connection, if you see what I mean.

Comment: I didn't get what you exactly want and where does this apache fits in your requirements. What specific use case you are solving. If you looking tunneling of http traffic over a persistent connection then you can achieve that through websockets. Pass your http packets through the websockets.

Comment: @MukeshVerma I want to tunnel TLS traffic through my web server. Apache must handle http requests and responses. No, I don't intend to tunnel http traffic but to use http to tunnel TLS.

Comment: What love you have for apache, when https proxies are there to handle this specific use case. Please tell me why you want apache.I am eager to know!!

Answer (score 0):

Afaik CONNECT request is sent by the browser to intermediate PROXY server and not directly to web server. So that once connect request is received the PROXY can create a direct duplex link between webserver and browser.

Comment: As @Quentin mentioned why you want to use apache httpd as https proxy. There are proxy servers designed for that specific use case. Why you specifically want to use Apache for this purpose ?

Comment: See my answer to Quentin above.